# SQLite mistake on joining tables

Tags: sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have following tables:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE products(
    '_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    'name' VARCHAR(20),
    'price' INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE orders(
    '_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    'order_number' INTEGER,
    'order_sum' INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE ord_details(
    '_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    'order_id' INTEGER,
    'product_id' INTEGER,
    'product_count' INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE ord_times(
    '_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    'order_id' INTEGER,
    'start_t' TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'end_t' TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

So, in tables have following data:

In **'products'** table

```
---------------------
1 | roll        | 100
2 | cheese      | 500
3 | burger      | 300
4 | mega burger | 550
```

In **'orders'** table

```
-------------
1 | 11 | 600
```

In **'ord_details'** table

```
--------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 2 | 1
```

In **'ord_times'** table

```
--------------------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
```

when I execute this SQL command and it gives incorrect result:

```
SELECT orders.order_number, products.name as prname, products.price, ord_details.product_count, orders.order_sum, ord_times.start_t, ord_times.end_t FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN ord_details ON orders._id=ord_details.order_id 
LEFT JOIN products ON ord_details.product_id=products._id
LEFT JOIN ord_times ON orders._id=ord_times.order_id
```

**Result:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11 | roll        | 100 | 1 | 600 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
11 | cheese      | 500 | 1 | 600 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
11 | burger      | 300 | 0 | 600 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
11 | mega burger | 550 | 0 | 600 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
```

**I'm expecting as following result:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11 | roll        | 100 | 1 | 600 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
11 | cheese      | 500 | 1 | 600 | 12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM | 12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM
```

When I execute this code in sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3080200 normally working:

[image]

but execute this SQL in android return incorrect result.
Here inserting code:

```
INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ("roll", 100);
INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ("cheese", 500);
INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ("burger", 300);
INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ("mega burger", 550);
INSERT INTO orders (order_number, order_sum) VALUES (11, 600);
INSERT INTO ord_details (order_id, product_id, product_count) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO ord_details (order_id, product_id, product_count) VALUES (1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO ord_times (order_id, start_t, end_t) VALUES (1,'12/23/2013 12:24:38 PM', '12/23/2013  12:27:02 PM');
```

**Why "ord_details.product_id=products._id" expression not working in android?**

Comment: Hm, [your exact setup except a missing comma in the orders table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9dacc/1) seems to give your expected result.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson you are right I did mistake when write question in Stackoverflow

Comment: -1 What you are reproducing is not possible. `orders LEFT JOIN ... products` wouldn't show unmatched `products`, only unmatched `orders`. Post your real SQL! Use [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) before posting non possible results.

Comment: @LS_dev If you need execute this SQLite scripts, download sqlite-shell-[win32/mac]-3080200.zip the following link:http://www.sqlite.org/download.html Then you can execute this SQLite scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN while joining the OrderDetails and Products table so the code will look like

```
SELECT orders.order_number, products.name as prname, products.price, 

ord_details.product_count, orders.order_sum, ord_times.start_t, ord_times.end_t FROM orders 

LEFT JOIN ord_details ON orders._id=ord_details.order_id 

JOIN products ON ord_details.product_id=products._id

LEFT JOIN ord_times ON orders._id=ord_times.order_id
```